# How do I view the details of a digital certificate .cer file?

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, certificate

I am using Windows and have been given a .cer file. How can I view the details of it?

Comment: Almost [official help](https://support.ssl.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/19/0/der-vs-crt-vs-cer-vs-pem-certificates-and-how-to-convert-them) might help you.

Answer (score 393, accepted):

OpenSSL will allow you to look at it if it is installed on your system, using the [OpenSSL x509 tool](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/x509.html).

```bash
openssl x509 -noout -text -in 'cerfile.cer';
```

The format of the .CER file might require that you specify a different encoding format to be explicitly called out.

```bash
openssl x509 -inform pem -noout -text -in 'cerfile.cer';
```

or

```bash
openssl x509 -inform der -noout -text -in 'cerfile.cer';
```

On Windows systems you can right click the .cer file and select Open. That will then let you view most of the meta data.

On Windows you run Windows certificate manager program using certmgr.msc command in the run window. Then you can import your certificates and view details.

Comment: I get "4726:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:632:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE" when I do this in Linux

Comment: What you mentioned about Windows works though, but is very hard to read the certificate details in the little window that is displayed

Comment: I've added some clarifications on some OpenSSL options to specify different encoding formats - given your error specifying DER format looks like it would work.

Comment: Thanks, "openssl x509 -inform der -in cerfile.cer -noout -text" worked!

Comment: Linux gui version: gcr-viewer.

Comment: when getting `:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio`" error, u will need to use the 3rd command given, with `-inform der`

Answer (score 46):

If you're using Windows, you can use console util

```
certutil -dump <file>
```

Comment: Where is that "certutil" from? The one from nss-utils on my systems doesn't have a "-dump" option.

Comment: It's system util. I have Windows 7. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/cc732443(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 13):

All answers here fail for MacOS. The only thing that works in Sierra and High Sierra is:

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in cerfile.cer -noout -text
```

Comment: Helvick's answer (last updated in 2014) contains this exact line.

Comment: Surely the necessary solution depends on the format of the certificate file, rather than the system it's used on?

Comment: I am on Mac OS Mojave. "$ openssl x509 -in host.crt.pem -noout -text" works fine without "inform der".

Comment: @user674669 The pem format is base64, which can be viewed with any text editor.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu xenial and OpenSSL 1.1.0h. The other answers did not

Answer (score 5):

You can import and preview it by **Powershell**:

```
Get-ChildItem –Path c:\file.cer | Import-Certificate –CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

then view it in Windows certmgr.msc or load directly to Powershell

```
SET-LOCATION CERT:\LOCALMACHINE\my
GET-CHILDITEM –RECURSE | FORMAT-LIST –PROPERTY *
```

or by Thumbprint

```
$cert = (Get-ChildItem –Path cert:\LocalMachine\My\AE53B1272E43C14545A448FB892F7C07A217A761)
```

Don't forget to IMPORT-MODULE PKI

Or you can also view, export, import, and delete certificates by using **Internet Explorer**.

To view certificates with Internet Explorer

1. In Internet Explorer, click Tools, then click Internet Options to
   display the Internet Options dialog box.
2. Click the Content tab.
3. Under Certificates, click Certificates. To view details of any
       certificate, select the certificate and click View.

Comment: `Import-Certificate` is not available for me (Win 7/PS 5)

Comment: Importing a cert is not a great idea if you only want to inspect it, perhaps to decide if it can be trusted or not.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but I saw no one provided a workable solution for windows 7 using only PowerShell. That didn't require the extra hassle of importing it into the certificate store,other tom foolery like using IE or certutil. I happened to have the same issue today, and this is the solution I came up with:

```
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate

$cert.Import("D:\mycert.cer")

$cert.GetEffectiveDateString() 
$cert.GetSerialNumber() 
$cert | get-member 
etc..
```

One thing the x509CErtificate class does not contain is the ability to read CRLs. In order to do that you have to use something like Mono since it has a class that will read them

Answer (score 5):

I found openssl quite limiting (cannot parse content of chain/bundle, output is quite noisy for my needs, ...), I have created [certinfo](https://github.com/pete911/certinfo) project on github, which can parse chain/bundle, accepts multiple files as argument and can get cert info from host as well if the argument is in the form of `host:port`.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, if you have Sun/Oracle/OpenJDK Java (or get and install it) you can use

```
keytool -printcert -v -file {filename}
# works for either PEM or DER, you don't need to specify
# but _very_ old Java (before 7 IIRC) doesn't handle PEM _with comments added_
```

Back in the days of NT and XP, Java was fashionable and widely promoted, and once MS gave up on their own version of JVM, Sun Java was often -- but not always -- preinstalled on Windows systems, while OpenSSL usually wasn't, so for a while this could have been a good solution. In 2010, when this Q was asked, it was still moderately common, but the numerous security vulnerabilities found in Sun's promoted "download and run everywhere" approach had begun to discourage people.

Now in 2023 I'd bet very few individual Windows users install Java on their own bat, although some enterprises (and I think some government agencies) still have Java applications in their workflows and require or at least encourage users (such as customers, or maybe citizens) to install it. Also a fair number of useful tools are coded in and thus require Java -- two I am personally familiar with are Eclipse (IDE) and Burp (HTTP/S interceptor/proxy). But if you don't already have Java, downloading 50-300MB only to get `keytool` to look at a cert (or certs) would be ... unwise.