# Export certificate after approving pending request standalone CA

Tags: certificate, certificate-authority

I have submitted a certificate request to my windows standalone-Certification Authority(CA). I already issued the certificate by approving the pending request, but I don't know how to export the .cer file from the CA.

Comment: Related post - [How do I view the details of a digital certificate .cer file?](https://serverfault.com/q/215606/329172)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you right click on the certificate in the **Issued Certificates** section of the MMC, you can select **All Tasks** and then **Export Binary Data**.

From the `Columns that contain binary data:` dropdown select **Binary Certificate**.  On the **Export options** choose **Save binary data to a file**.

[image]

Click <kbd>OK</kbd> and then select a directory on the disk to save the certificate file.  For the best results on a Windows system save the file with a name like `cert_subject.crt`.

Comment: Anyone knows some way to achieve it in Powershell? `certutil -view` is not useful for it.

Comment: @James Don't know of any way using the built in Microsoft commandlets, A web search sent me to this module, that might make it possible.  https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSPKI/3.2.7.0 https://www.sysadmins.lv/projects/pspki/default.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link. I didn't found it in my previous research and it will help.

Answer (score 3):

Double click the certificate to open **Certificate** window. Go to **Details** tab and click <kbd>Copy to File...</kbd> button (Refer screenshot) to start the certificate export wizard:

[image]

Then you will see below step in the wizard which gives you the option of saving the `*.cer` file on disk:

[image]